# Unable to open the hangout meeting link through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api, hangouts-api

I am trying to open hangout meeting link through javaScript but it's redirecting to 500 error page. but when I try to visit the same link in browser directly it's working.

I know it's sounds stupid but I am facing it.

below is my code

```
  joinMeeting =  () => {
            window.open(
               "https://meet.google.com/qry-gwik-ory", // when I open this link in browser it work
                '_blank' 
              );    
    }
 <button type="button" onClick={()=>{this.joinMeeting()}} className="btn-flat">Join</button>
```

Comment: I am also looking for the answer.
HTTP500 occurs when opening a hangout link in HTML as well as in JavaScript.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by opening as follows: `window.open(meeting.hangoutUrl, "_blank","noreferrer");`  , the noreferrer is the key.